# When running Update-database or Enable-migration it fails with error "Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s)",

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

When running `Update-database` or `Enable-migration` it fails with error

> "Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s)"

, However when I run `"EntityFrameworkCore\Add-migration"` or `"EntityFrameworkCore\Update-database"` It successfully adds and runs the migration. 
This didn't happen before and suddenly I'm having to do this. 
I just want to know if this is something I should be worried about and the reason why `Add-Migration` or `Update-database` doesn't work but works when prefixed with `"EnityFrameworkCore\"`

Not really sure what code to show here because i'm not sure where the issue in the code is, if it even is an issue

Comment: Are you sure that your solution doesn't contain any reference to Entity Framework (without core)?

Comment: @grek40 how would I check this?